# why is my FAB animation going out of screen with Material BottomAppBar?

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design

So i got this working and it's great

[image]

Then i tried to set the parent FAB on the right with:

`binding.bottomAppBar.fabAlignmentMode = BottomAppBar.FAB_ALIGNMENT_MODE_END`

It works but now the parent FAB animation goes out of screen.

[image]

Here is a better look of what is going on:

[image]

Open animation:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true">
<rotate
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="45"
    android:duration="300" />
```

Close Animation:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true">
<rotate
    android:fromDegrees="45"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="0"
    android:duration="300"
    />
```

Activity XML:

```
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar.Colored"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="end"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/addFav"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar"/>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

How can i fix this? The child FABs animations work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what's happening.

1. When the XML is inflated, the FAB is at the center. So `pivotX` is now center of the screen.
2. You set `fabAlignmentMode` programmatically in Java/Kotlin after inflation.
3. When rotation starts, `pivotX` is still using the value from inflation point and hence using old value.
4. The FAB is rotated about the center of its previous location and hence goes out of screen. Notice the curve in the motion of the FAB in the second GIF.

Setting the alignment in XML using `fabAlignmentMode` should resolve your issue.

Comment: Just tested this in a new project to be sure and it didn't worked, i added a new GIF from below if you want to check it out.

Comment: @Joaco are you setting any attribute on the FAB that is related to position?

Comment: Nope, i added the xml too.